# Working with original vectors within another class

Tags: c++

I've got homework to do for my University. The task is to do 2 classes (Player and Team) where the first one creates 10 players with attributes and the second one groups 5 of them into one team and the other 5 into second team. Here are these classes.

```
class Player {
public:
    string name;
    string surname;
    int height;
    vector<string> skills;

    // Default constructor
    Player(string name, string surname, int height, vector<string> skills) : name(name), surname(surname), 
        height(height), skills(skills) {}

    // Copy constructor
    Player(const Player &player) : name(player.name), surname(player.surname), height(player.height), 
        skills(player.skills) {}

    // Method showing data
    string show_data() const {
        stringstream ss;
        string s;

        ss << 
            name << " " <<
            surname << " " <<
            height << " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                ss << skills[i] << " ";
            }
            ss << "\n";
        s = ss.str();
        return s;
    }

    void change_height(int height) {
        this->height = height;
    }

class Team {
public:
    vector<Player> players;
    vector<Player> copy_p;

    // Default constructor
    Team(vector<Player> players) : players(players) {}

    // Copy constructor
    Team(const Team &(vector<Player> copy_p)) : players(copy_p) {}

    // Method showing data
    void show_data() const {
        for (auto const &player : players) {
            cout << player.show_data();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code that divides players into 2 teams.

```
vector<Player> lfc = { p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 };
Team liverpool(lfc);
vector<Player> rm = { p6,p7,p8,p9,p10 };
Team real_madrit(rm);
```

Alright, we are getting to the heart of the problem. When it comes to change height of one player (method change_height), it does not print it out when I want to show the data of the team. The height remains as it was set default.

```
// Changing the height of one player in the second team
p7.change_height(195);
cout << p7.height << endl;

// Again displaying data of 3 teams
liverpool.show_data();
cout << endl;
real_madrit.show_data();
cout << endl;
real_madrit_copy.show_data();
cout << endl;
```

I think that I am not working on original objects within class Team or something similar. 
The question arises how can I modify this program to print the proper value after doing changes in class Player so that class Team should print out modified and actual data?

Comment: Note that your code as written is ill-formed and won't compile. Please provide a MVCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem here is how you access the players. 
In your code, you are copying the `Player`s into their teams, and then modifying the `Player`s that you copied in the class, thus not affecting the `Player`s in the `Team` class itself.

In my opinion, you should access them through the instances of the `Team` class, like `real_madrid.players[i].change_height(n)`. By doing so, you don't need anymore to explicitly instantiate the `Player` objects and then insert them in the `Player` vectors used to construct the `Team`s, but you could directly construct them in their respective vector, using `emplace_back()` (and thus avoiding useless copies).

```
std::vector<Player> lfc;
lfc.reserve(5);    // Using reserve() to avoid copies
lfc.emplace_back("Player", "Zero",  0, skills);
lfc.emplace_back("Player", "One",   1, skills);
lfc.emplace_back("Player", "Two",   2, skills);
lfc.emplace_back("Player", "Three", 3, skills);
lfc.emplace_back("Player", "Four",  4, skills);
Team liverpool(lfc);

std::vector<Player> rm;
rm.reserve(5);
rm.emplace_back("Player", "Five",  5, skills);
rm.emplace_back("Player", "Six",   6, skills);
rm.emplace_back("Player", "Seven", 7, skills);
rm.emplace_back("Player", "Eight", 8, skills);
rm.emplace_back("Player", "Nine",  9, skills);
Team real_madrid(rm);

real_madrid.show_data();
std::cout << "------------------------\n";
real_madrid.players[2].change_height(195);
real_madrid.show_data();
```

This code will generate the following output:

```
Player Five 5 No_skills 
Player Six 6 No_skills 
Player Seven 7 No_skills 
Player Eight 8 No_skills 
Player Nine 9 No_skills 
------------------------
Player Five 5 No_skills 
Player Six 6 No_skills 
Player Seven 195 No_skills    // The value changed successfully :)
Player Eight 8 No_skills 
Player Nine 9 No_skills
```

The only change I made to your classes was using a range-based loop when getting the skills in the `show_data()` method, to avoid getting out of bounds if the skills were less then five.

```
std::string show_data() const {
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << 
        name << " " <<
        surname << " " <<
        height << " ";
        for (const auto& skill : skills)
            ss << skill << " ";
        ss << "\n";
    return ss.str();
}
```